# System.InvalidOperationException value exception in Placeholder with SXA installed in Sitecore 9 update 1

Tags: sxa

Have you encountered this issue in SXA?
[image]

To re-create the issue, In the Experience Editor Click Presentation Details > Click Final Layout tab > click Edit > click Placeholder Settings > click Add

I tried installing a fresh Sitecore 9 instance then installed SXA 1.6 and Sitecore PowerShell Extension 4.7.2 and I encounter the same error. Anyone has info on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: SC 9 update 1?  According to documentation, SXA 1.6 is compatible with 9 Upd 1 or 8.6 Upd 6.  So, just tmaking sure.

Comment: Yep, Sc9 update 1

Answer (score 2):

The SXA team is now aware of this. Unfortunately, we don't have enough time to fix it in 1.7. We'll handle it in 1.8. For now, please can add placeholder settings by other means.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and encountered very same issue:

[image]

It is the same also for "Shared Layout".

Best would be to create ticket to Sitecore Support to sort that out for 1.7 version :).